# How can I tell what's redirecting a web page request?

Tags: redirect, wordpress, lamp

For some reason I'm getting redirected to https on my local, which is weird. Is there any way I can trace where the request goes?

My question is more for a general purpose because this specific case isn't the only time I've needed a tool to figure out something like this, but for those about to ask, I'm using LAMP stack on mac OSX and it's a wordpress site. This is the first time that I've run into the problem with wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Typically when Wordpress redirects it's one of two things:

1. .htaccess settings
2. Home/Site URL settings in the wp_options table of your Wordpress database (default prefix)

As for how to see what's redirecting your best bet would be to use strace from the host:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace

For simple header reads to get an idea what may be going on curl is super useful:

https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl

Comment: I checked both those wordpress settings, they're normal.

Comment: Did you use curl as suggested to see if any of the headers returned yield a clue?